# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection') mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to MongoDB.I am trying to launch a data server. And am getting the following error when I run `node dataserver.js` and visit the following endpoint `http://localhost:3600/artifacts/`

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
    at /home/gatwiri/MEAN/sbom-dataserver.js:41:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/gatwiri/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/gatwiri/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/gatwiri/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/gatwiri/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/gatwiri/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at param (/home/gatwiri/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at param (/home/gatwiri/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:376:14)
    at Function.process_params (/home/gatwiri/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:421:3)
    at next (/home/gatwiri/MEAN/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
```

console output

```
GEThttp://localhost:3600/artifacts
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 1ms]

Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:3600/favicon.ico (“default-src”).
```

Tried to search for a solution in StackOverflow but nothing has fitted my problem so far.
Below is my code:

dataserver.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var db
const dbName = 'my-test'
const port = 3600
let table = 'artifact'
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on ' + port + '.')
})

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

app.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  res.send("Recognized endpoints on this server include '/artifacts' and '/artifacts/NAME'.")
})
app.route('/artifacts').get((req, res) => {
  db.collection(table).find().toArray((err, artifact) => {
    if (err) throw err
    var artifacts = []
    artifact.forEach((value) => {
      artifacts.push({scriptname: value.scriptname})
    })
    res.send(artifacts)
  })
})
app.route('/artifacts/:scriptname').get((req, res) => {
  const scriptname = req.params['scriptname']
  db.collection(table).findOne({scriptname: scriptname}, function(err, artifact) {
  if (err) throw err
    res.send({
      scriptname: artifact.scriptname,
      version: artifact.version,
      cdn: artifact.cdn
    })
  })
})

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  db.collection(table).find().toArray((err, artifact) => {
        if (err) throw err
        artifact.forEach((value) => {
    })
    client.close()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are returning nothing in the MongoClient.connect function, check the return type/value
2. the `db variable` you are using in the route `/artifacts` is the top level db variable that is created, which is garbage value.
3. the `const db` in MongoClient.connect is local variable and hence the db var that you created at the top of your code wont be changed and hence the error you are getting.